# Get a reference to a list in a python module and iterate over it

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to throw together a little site which has a number of pages with forms. In those forms, I'd like to add some drop-downs and power the contents with lists stored in a module in my project

The lists are basically being used as Enums (I'm stuck on Python 3.4 and apparently Python has managed to get this far without enum support)

I don't want to have to pass in every possible list as part of the model (it's inefficient), but conversely keeping track of which lists are used where and making sure the models are populated as appropriate seems like a lot of hassle for something so trivial.

So... I'd like to write a macro that will take a list name and generate a drop-down for it. My initial attempt:

```
{% macro dropdown(name, selected='') -%}
    <select name="{{ name }}">
        {% for item in Server.Enums.__dict__({{name}}) %}
            <option>{{item}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
{%- endmacro %}
```

fails because I can't get a reference the Enums module to work.

How can I expose the Enums module and the list inside it to Jinja without explicitly adding it to the model?

Comment: [Enums were add to Python in 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/enum.html).

Comment: @dirn That's handy thanks, but the question remains... How can I reference them from inside a jinja2 template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reference something in a template, you need to pass it to the template. This can be done in one of two ways.

First, you can pass it in through `render_template`:

```
from somewhere import something

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', something=something)
```

If you want to do this for every template, though, this can become cumbersome and error-prone. To provide something to every template, you can use a [context processor](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors).

```
from somewhere import something

@app.context_processor
def inject_things():
    return {'something': something}
```